# Problemas subiendo un archivo a una Api desde React

Tags: django, reactjs, api

Estoy creando una app que sube imágenes a través de un formulario creado en React, este formulario posteriormente es enviado a través de fetch a una Api creada en Django, el tema es que cuando recibo la respuesta del servidor me retorna el objeto pero en el campo photo me aparece null, no subiendo así la imagen. estoy usando FormData como me aconsejaron para la subida de archivos a través de la Api. pero aun así me aparece null no pudiendo resolver mi problema si a alguien ya le paso estaría agradecido con alguna pista.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

export class CreatePost extends React.Component {

state = {
    newPost: [],
    categorias: [],
    selectedFile: null
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getCategories();
}

getCategories = () => {
    console.log('categoriasss');
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
    const secretKey = localStorage.getItem('key');

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `token ${secretKey}`
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('recibe la info para categorias', resp.status);
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(info => {
        console.log('recibe las categorias', info);
        this.setState({
            categorias: this.state.categorias.concat(info)
        })
    })
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    // const { name, value } = e.target;
    // let newObj = { [name]: value };
    // const newData = {...this.state.newPost, ...newObj};
    this.setState({
        // newPost: newData,
        selectedFile: e.target.files[0]
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('posted ', this.state.selectedFile);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)


    const secretKey = localStorage.getItem('key');
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {

            'Accept': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `token ${secretKey}`
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('respuesta de la subida ', resp.status);
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(respuesta => {
        console.log('respuesta', respuesta);
    })
}



render() {
    const categories = this.state.categorias.map((categoria, id) => {
        console.log('y? ', categoria.category);
    })
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <h1>Create page</h1>
            <form>
                {/* <input name='title' placeholder='title' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input> */}
                {/* <input name='author' placeholder='author' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='description' placeholder='description' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='content' placeholder='content' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='category' placeholder='category' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input> */}
                <input name='photo' type="file" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
                <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Crea</button>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Can you try         `this.setState({
            categorias: [...this.state.categorias, ...info]
        })` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tema resuelto, lo que me falto es colocar el nombre del campo puesto en el modelo de la api que en este caso era 'photo', en cambio, yo estaba colocando 'file' por ende este no me tomaba al momento de enviar la data a la api. Ademas, falto colocar dentro de los headers 'multipart/form-data'. Adjunto el código de solución.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export class CreatePost extends React.Component {

state = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    selectedFile: null
}


handleImage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedFile: e.target.files[0]
    })
}

handleTitle = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        title: e.target
    })
}

handleDescription = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        description: e.target
    })
}

handleContent = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        content: e.target
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('posted ', this.state.selectedFile);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', this.state.selectedFile)
    formData.append('title', this.state.title.value)
    formData.append('description', this.state.description.value)
    formData.append('content', this.state.content.value)


    const secretKey = localStorage.getItem('key');
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
    axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: `token ${secretKey}`
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.status);
    })
}



render() {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <h1>Create page</h1>
            <form>
                <input name='title' placeholder='title' onChange={e => this.handleTitle(e)}></input>
                <input name='description' placeholder='description' onChange={e => this.handleDescription(e)}></input>
                <input name='content' placeholder='content' onChange={e => this.handleContent(e)}></input>
                {/* <input name='category' placeholder='category' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input> */}
                <input name='photo' type="file" onChange={e => this.handleImage(e)}/>
                <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Crea</button>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}
```